# Show that two plane sets are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Would some kind soul be able to help me understand a question in topology?

Let $A = \lbrace (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1 \rbrace $ and $B = \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 < x^2 + y^2 < 4 \rbrace.$

I wish to show that $A$ is homeomorphic to $B$.

While I know that a homeomorphism between the two sets is $$f(\mathbf{v}) = \left(\frac{\lvert\lvert\mathbf{v}\rvert\rvert + 1}{\lvert\lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert\rvert}\right) \mathbf{v},$$

(I understand that this is a continuous mapping with continuous inverse), my difficulty is in understanding why this is a good choice for a homeomorphism. I'm just having trouble understanding how $f$ takes a vector in $A$ to a vector in $B$.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: $A$ is not homeomorphic to $B$.

Comment: Surely you mean the punctured open unit ball?

Comment: Indeed Jonas, I'll edit the question as there is a typo! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jonas points out, the sets you give aren't homeomorphic.  A is an open circle of radius 1 and B is an open ring with inner radius 1 and outer radius 2.  However, if you remove the origin from A you're in business.

Now the mapping you give stretches every vector in A to make the larger ring B.  In particular, the "+1" ensures there are no points within radius 1 of the origin. If we took the closure of A, the longest vectors in the set cl(A) would have magnitude 1, so for these $(||v||+1)\frac{v}{||v||}$ make up the boundary of B.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help. The explanation that the "+1" ensures that there are no points within radius 1 of the origin especially :) Thank you again.

Comment: Just as an aside, would one be able to use a similar method to show that the plane with the origin removed is homeomorphic to the plane with a closed disc removed? Thanks again.

Comment: No problem!  Yes that follows a very similar logic.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot.